# Is "self" the only way to call another method of the same instance from an instance method?

Tags: objective-c

I have been reading Apple's "The Objective-C Programming Language", I noticed that if you have say,

Class A /w methods MA and MB, where MA calls MB with "[self MB]".

If you subclass Class A, lets call it SubClass A, and over-ride MB. Made an instance of SubClass A and call MA, it will use the new MB. Now if you call "[super MA]" instead, it will **still** use the new MB.

Am I correct?

So I was wondering if "self" is the "right" way to go about this, calling other methods in the same instance, or if it's only used for special situations like covering initializers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `self` is the right way to send a message to the same instance that the method is executing on.

One of the big things to keep in mind about the object model of languages like Objective-C is that, conceptually, you are not "calling methods" — you're *sending messages*. You're telling the object what to do, not how to do it. You shouldn't normally have to think about what precise method will execute when you send a message — the object is expected to respond appropriately. So if somebody has overridden this "MB" method, presumably the new behavior is how he wants the object to respond when it gets an "MB" message. If somebody has overridden "MB" such that it is no longer usable the way the old method was, then that sounds like a bug.

Comment: Alright "self" it is. Thanks everyone.

Still it feels kind of dangerous. 
I was thinking I could have a class with an instance method (MA) that does a calculation in some way, then when I subclass it have it done in another way by over-ridding some of the other methods that it (MA) depends on. But later decide I like the old way as an option and try to "re-implement" by passing a message to super and have it not work right...

As for "calling" ... old habit, studied Java first - as well as C which has functions calling one another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.
Using self inside your class is the right way to go if you want to call methods that are in the same class.
'self' represents the current instance of the class where you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is the right way to go. Every method in Objective-C can be thought of as "virtual" (in C++ parlance).

Comment: They are methods, not functions.  "Function" in Objective-C has the same meaning as in C.

Answer (score 0):

In SubClass A, you don't need to make an instance, you can access any function of subClass A by sing self.
making new object makes a new instance, so it reintialize all the property for that instance.
so you can't do any thing right with this.

```
self always be right for accessing same class methods and property.
```

Hope now you can understand why self rather than making other new instance.

And [super MA] must call method of class A's MA method, no case in which MB calls for calling MA.

I have test it, there is no bug all OOPs concept follow in objective c you can call super class method by calling method on super keyword.

So Probably you are doing some thing wrong. just check it.

Comment: I was thinking I could have a class with an instance method (MA) that does a calculation in some way, then when I subclass it have it done in another way by over-ridding some of the other methods that it's (MA) depends on. But later decide I like the old way as an option and try to "re-implement" by passing a message to super and have it not work right... Seems "dangerous".

The "make an instance" was just part of the "example".

Comment: I have test it, there is no bug all OOPs concept follow here.

Comment: Alright then. I suppose it's something I just have to watch out for and try not to shoot oneself in the foot.